# C Buffer underflows definition and associated risk

Tags: c, buffer

According to Wikipedia:
In computing, buffer underrun or buffer underflow is a state occurring when a buffer used to communicate between two devices or processes is fed with data at a lower speed than the data is being read from it.

From apple's secure coding guide:
Fundamentally, buffer underflows occur when two parts of your code disagree about the size of a buffer or the data in that buffer. For example, a fixed-length C string variable might have room for 256 bytes, but might contain a string that is only 12 bytes long.

Apple's definition complements the idea of buffer overflow.

1. Which of these definitions is technically more sound?
2. Is buffer underflow a major security concern? I have the habbit of using large buffers to poll and read() from serial ports or sockets (although I do use bzero()). Is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Those are two different usages of the word "underflow".  As they are describing two different things, I don't think you can compare them on technical soundness.
2. Buffer underflow, as per Apple's definition, could be a weakness.  See http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/124.html.

Answer (score 2):

2) ' I do use bzero()). Is this the right thing to do?'

Almost certainly no.  The system calls return how many bytes have been received.  If you're absolutely certain that you are going to receive text-style data with no embedded nulls, and wish to use C-style string lib calls on it, just push one null onto the end of the buffer, (this often means reading one less byte than the declared buffer length, to ensure thare is enough space for the null).  In all other cases, just don't bother with the terminator at all.  It's going to be either pointless or dangerous.

bzero() is just a waste of cycles in the case of network buffers.  I don't care how many web page examples there are or how many sources say 'vars/buffers must be initialized'.   It's rubbish.